# phpmailer sending but not receiving

Tags: php, phpmailer

Just finished setting up PHPMailer to send the PDF that is created from my html form (using FPDF, the pdf file is created without a problem). It says sent successfully but im not receiving anything?

I have checked other peoples code and it looks just like mine. Is there anything im doing wrong with the PHPmailer code at the bottom?

my host,username and password are all correct 100% as far as I know we dont use TLS or SSL. Maybe that has something to do with this?

My code:

```
require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
$mail->Host ="*****";
$Mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication;
$mail->Username = "*****";
$mail->Password = "****";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->From = "******";
$mail->FromName = "Jurgen Hof";

$mail->addAddress("testingaccount23@gmail.com", "Tester");
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject  = 'Test Leave Application';
$mail->Body     = 'Test.';
$mail->AddAttachment("/var/www/html/leaveform/AlpineLeaveApplication.pdf");  

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}
echo 'Email Sent Successfully!';
?>
```

Comment: If code does not throws error, than it's working fine. Maybe issue is with email address/spam folder/blacklisted sender?

Comment: What's your smtp debug output? There's any error?
Maybe your mail simply goes to spam?

Comment: i put the wrong username and password on purpose and it still said sent successfully. So theres definetely something wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting lots of SMTP properties, but not actually asking it to send via SMTP! Add this:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
```

Your browser will then explode with debug output, so I suggest you turn down `SMTPDebug = 2`.